# CompletableFuture run task in a non-blocking way with limited threads in JAVA

Tags: java, completable-future

I have defined a pool of 2 threads like this:

```java
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

Now I have three tasks, two of which are blocking and one which is non-blocking.

```java
CompletableFuture<Integer> blocking1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(callableTask1, executor);
CompletableFuture<Integer>blocking2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(callableTask2, executor);

CompletableFuture<Void> nonBlocking = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println("nonBlocking task's thread:  " + Thread.currentThread());
    System.out.println("Non Blocking task");
});
```

Both `callableTask1` and `callableTask2` are blocking as it makes the thread wait. Currently, to print "Non-Blocking task" it is waiting for any of the blocking task to free up the thread. I want any thread to not wait for any of the task to finish and process `nonBlocking` task immediately.

The output should be:

"Non Blocking Task" -> first
"callable Task1" or "callable Task2" -> second

Comment: Your `nonBlocking` task does not wait for anything. The code as posted does already have the behavior you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

## Another executor service

If some tasks are holding up pressing tasks, create another executor service.

```
Executor executorPooled = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Executor executorPriority = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```